# how do I rotate a direction Vector3 upwards by an angle in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, quaternions

this is my direction vector:

```
new Vector3(
    target.transform.position.x - projectile.position.x,
    0,
    target.transform.position.z - projectile.position.z
).normalized
```

I tried multiplying it by `Quaternion.AngleAxis(45, Vector3.up)` but that simply doesn't work
All other orientations like Vector3.left, right, etc. don't help either

The only thing I could observe is the way that the angle changes when I move the target or projectile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. Use cross product to get the axis you need, use that in `AngleAxis`, then finally apply that rotation to your starting direction:

```
Vector3 RotateTowardsUp(Vector3 start, float angle)
{
    // if you know start will always be normalized, can skip this step
    start.Normalize();

    Vector3 axis = Vector3.Cross(start, Vector3.up);

    // handle case where start is colinear with up
    if (axis == Vector3.zero) axis = Vector3.right;

    return Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, axis) * start;
}
```